# Help with VGA KVM switch

Tags: arduino, vga, automation

Hi for my work im triying to implement a VGA KVM switch to replace a manual switch that the production line workers use to switch between Quality control test, to replace that i tought about using a kvm switch with an arduino to make that process automatically.
the program will be switching between all 4 test after each one is complete
but i dont know how a kvm switch works to read each signal to be able to do what i have in mind.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Hi, Please can you [edit] your post to add a single, clear, reasonably-scoped question? At the moment this reads like a "whole project" question, where you need help understanding a KVM (which is probably USBx2 + VGA, but could be PS/2x2 + VGA etc.) and then controlling that with an Arduino. There is no single question there, meaning that it isn't a good "fit" for this site. Please read the [tour], the [help] & the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931) for more info about Stack Exchange. Specific questions are expected here; questions which are "too broad" may be closed. Thanks.